# Setting up Integration tests in a laravel package

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, package, integration-testing

Currently struggling to setup integration tests within a package I'm writing.

For the integrations tests I will need to have access to a Laravel environment so I can access things such as Artisan::call('migrate') and access the database.

Currently I'm guessing I need to have any tests extend the Laravel TestCase class, bootstrapping a Laravel environment. Although I cannot workout how I can call this file into my package.

Secondly while developing packages in workbench would I need to use Artisan::call('migrate', '--bench="vendor/package"') or Artisan::call('migrate', '--package="vendor/package"') this is confusing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need to create an instance of Laravel, along with a database that PHPUnit can access to run the tests against real-world data sets. Not brittle mocks. Firstly you should be developing your packages in isolation for a number of reasons, one being workbench is now deprecated in Laravel 5.

So firstly we need to `dev-require` the Laravel framework into our project:

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1",
    "laracasts/testdummy": "~2.0",
    "laravel/laravel": "dev-develop"
},
```

Now we can create an abstract class called `DbTestCase` that all our tests will extend from. Within this class we will be spinning up an instance of Laravel and an *in memory* SQLite database for speed.

If we extend the native Laravel test class `Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase` some of the work has already been done for us. We simple need to create a method that returns an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`.

```
/**
 * Boots the application.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Application
 */
public function createApplication()
{
    $app = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/laravel/laravel/bootstrap/app.php';

    $app->register('Path\To\Your\PackageServiceProvider');

    $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

    return $app;        
}
```

notice the line `$app->register('Path\To\Your\PackageServiceProvider');` this is important. Include your package service provider path here, so we register it with our Laravel instance that lives in our packages `/vendor` folder.

Now we have a Laravel application running, we need to setup the in-memory SQLite database. Simple, Laravel's `TestCase` has a `setUp()` function that is run before ever test, lets do it there:

```
/**
 * Setup DB before each test.
 *
 * @return void  
 */
public function setUp()
{ 
    parent::setUp();

    $this->app['config']->set('database.default','sqlite'); 
    $this->app['config']->set('database.connections.sqlite.database', ':memory:');

    $this->migrate();
}
```

I won't give to much explanation as its quite readable. As you can see on the last line we are also calling `$this->migrate()` which obviously runs our migrations each time we run a test giving us a fresh DB to test against. Lets look at how that works:

```
/**
 * run package database migrations
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function migrate()
{ 
    $fileSystem = new Filesystem;
    $classFinder = new ClassFinder;

    foreach($fileSystem->files(__DIR__ . "/../src/Migrations") as $file)
    {
        $fileSystem->requireOnce($file);
        $migrationClass = $classFinder->findClass($file);

        (new $migrationClass)->up();
    }
}
```

Not to go into too much detail, basically what we are doing here is looking into the `src/Migrations` folder of the package requiring all the files and then running their migrations. Its rough and needs more safety checks (i will do that in the future) but it works.

**Why not Artisan::call('migrate') ??**

Simple! In Laravel 5 the command `php artisan migrate --package='vendor/package'` has been deprecated. Developers are now expected to create their own commands to generate and move migration files to the proper location in the application. This is a much more flexible approach.

Comment: I'm not able to use ClassFinder in Laravel 5.4. Is there an alternative to this in 5.4? I'm getting the error Class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\ClassFinder' not found

Answer (score 8):

Although this question already has an accepted answer, I strongly recommend to use the [**orchestra/testbench**](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench) package.

Add this package in the `require-dev` section of your package's `composer.json` and make sure to extend any test class from this package's `TestCase` as described in the README.

This package is able to load custom Service Providers, register custom aliases, etc. while spinning up a complete Laravel environment for testing.

Comment: Good answer i will investigate and possibly mark yours as the correct one